# Numpy how to take covariance of 2d array and turn it into a 3d array?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, covariance

Lets say I have an array of size m x n.

```
x = [[4,5,3,6],
      [6,3,4,7],
      ...,
      [3,4,6,4]]
```

Using `numpy.cov()`

how do I get a covariance matrix of m x n x n?

Comment: In my experience, a MxN matrix typically represents M observations of an N-dimensional variable. The (empirical) covariance is then an [NxN matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Calculating_the_sample_covariance). It's not obvious to me what calculation would produce an MxNxN matrix from an MxN matrix.

Comment: this would be for something like m observations by n features. This new array is an array of matrices. It should be m classes by n features by n features

Comment: Hmm, well, that's definitely something different from a covariance matrix. Where do the classes come from? I think this will be impossible to answer without much more detail.